# inserting into python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The default behavior for python dictionary is to create a new key in the dictionary if that key does not already exist. For example:

```
d = {}
d['did not exist before'] = 'now it does'
```

this is all well and good for most purposes, but what if I'd like python to do nothing if the key isn't already in the dictionary. In my situation:

```
for x in exceptions:
    if masterlist.has_key(x):
        masterlist[x] = False
```

in other words, i don't want some incorrect elements in exceptions to corrupt my masterlist. Is this as simple as it gets? it *FEELS* like I should be able to do this in one line inside the for loop (i.e., without explicitly checking that x is a key of masterlist)

UPDATE:
To me, my question is asking about the lack of a parallel between a list and a dict. For example:

```
l = []
l[0] = 2 #fails
l.append(2) #works
```

with the subclassing answer, you could modify the dictionary (maybe "safe_dict" or "explicit_dict" to do something similar:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = '1' #would fail in my world
d.insert('a','1') #what my world is missing
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. There's nothing wrong with making it clear what you are doing, in fact, it helps you to understand what it actually does...

Comment: well, i'm going to play devils advocate here and say that when you use the default behavior, you can't tell if you're inserting or modifying. which is less than completely explicit.

Comment: :) If you want it to be any more explicit, you're going to have to use a statically typed language, I'm afraid. (To make sure you understand what I mean: `foo = "bar"` in Python can mean initialization or modification of the variable (or rather: re-initialization) - Other languages require you to define a variable, in that case you know that it is new. Why should a dict be any more strict? I'm sure that *that* is an aspect you like about python. A one-liner for a single value would be: `d[k] = v if k not in d else d[k]` -- but it's not very nice ;)

Comment: AHA! Thanks, @phant0m! great comment. sometimes when you're in the forrest you can't see the trees. or in this case, in the dynamically typed language you can't see the....types? ha, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can inherit a `dict` class, override it's `__setitem__` to check for existance of key (or do the same with monkey-patching only one instance).

Sample class:

```python
class a(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        dict.__setitem__(self, 'a', 'b')

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.has_key(key):
          dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

a = a()
print a['a'] # prints 'b'
a['c'] = 'd'
# print a['c'] - would fail
a['a'] = 'e'
print a['a'] # prints 'e'
```

You could also use some function to make setting values without checking for existence simpler.
However, I though it would be shorter... Don't use it unless you need it in many places.

Comment: But then how do you set the initial keys? I guess in the constructor or by adding a special method.

Comment: I would add: `*args, **kwargs` and pass them to the dict's original contructor.

Comment: @phant0m Yes, you're absolutely right. I'll also make my post a community wiki.

Comment: This could be a bug or a feature, but you can still add keys using `update()`. You may want to override this method too if you don't want that behavior.

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`.update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
masterlist.update((x, False) for x in exceptions if masterlist.has_key(x))
```

Comment: ...is the for loop really eliminated?

Comment: Yes and no. it's a generator.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `in` instead of `has_key`, which is a little nicer.

```
for x in exceptions:
    if x in masterlist:
        masterlist[x] = False
```

But I don't see the issue with having an `if` statement for this purpose.

Comment: yeah like I was *trying* to say, there is no issue here whatsoever. just wondering if there's a more succinct way of doing it.

Comment: Writing a whole new dict subclass is more succinct?

Comment: @FogleBird, if you have these loops in a few different places, probably.

Comment: well...i think the answer is "there is no more succinct way without subclassing dict" edit: "OR going statically typed" as @phant0m points out

Comment: More succinct in actual use. Harder to keep the semantics straight, though. When you see what looks like a `dict` being used, you have to remember the special behavior.

Comment: @kindall, agreed. I would make a different api for this "safe_dict", such that you'd have to call an insert() method to add new elements and use the regular indexing method to modify values.

Answer (score 1):

For long lists try to use the `&` operator with `set()` function embraced with `()`:

```
    for x in (set(exceptions) & set(masterlist)):
        masterlist[x] = False
        #or masterlist[x] = exceptions[x]
```

It'll improve the reading and the iterations at the same time by reading the masterlist's keys only once.